# How to change the internal name of a list?

Tags: 2010, 2013

How to change the internal name of a sharepoint list ? Are there any drawbacks if i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete and re-create. And that has serious drawbacks.

If this is on-premises, you can use the Export-SPWeb / Import-SPWeb cmdlets to preserve the data.